# Unabe to send Notification using FirebaseCloudMessaging

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

**Problem**
How to send Birthday Notification's using FireBaseCloudMessaging.

**Solution**

I have implemented the following code by looking at sample example's but I am having difficulty in sending notification to a user or group of users.

> Can anyone guide me how to send Notification to a user?
>
> I am only stuck at one step

**Below is the Code**

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/notification", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void autoNotification() {
    int pageSize=2000;
    Page<User> users=null;
    int page=0;
    List<User> birthdays=null;
    do {
        users = userService.getAllUsers(new PageRequest(page,pageSize));
        birthdays=new ArrayList();
        LocalDate currentDate = new LocalDate();
        for (User user : users) {
            LocalDate dob=user.getDob();
            System.out.println("Date of Birth is "+dob);
            System.out.println("CurrentDate is "+currentDate.toString());
            if(currentDate.equals(dob)){
                System.out.println("Yes they match");
                birthdays.add(user);
            }
        }
    }while (users.hasNext());

    System.out.println(birthdays);
    System.out.println(birthdays.size());

    fcmService.sendBirthDayNotificationToUser(birthdays);
}
}
 public void sendBirthDayNotificationToUser(List<User> users) {
    System.out.println("Sending Notification ");
    List<String> registrationIds = new ArrayList<>();
    for (User user : users) {
        registrationIds.add();//What should be set here so that I can send to registered users.
    }

    Message message = new Message.Builder()
            .addData("type", "Default")
            .addData("title","Happy Birthday")
            .addData("content","Happy Birthday to you")
            .build();
    sendNotification(registrationIds,message);
}



public void sendNotification(List<String> registrationIds,Message message)
{
    Sender sender = new Sender(API_KEY);
    try {
        MulticastResult result = sender.send(message, registrationIds, 2);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOG.error("IOException", e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what exactly you are you doing, I assume you are trying to send downstream messages using the Admin SDK, which I do not have experience with, but I do have experience using the HTTP and XMPP APIs.

Based on my experience, you should add the "token id" of the users you want to send the messages to, I mean, your code should be something like:

```
 for (User user : users) {
        registrationIds.add(token_id_for_user);
    }
```

The token Id, is something that the client applications know (the android or IOS application), you can read information here "https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client" about how the application receives information about their current token id.

Basically the mobile application will register a class extending "FirebaseInstanceIdService" and the FCM API will notify the application with the token value through the method "onTokenRefresh". You can use this values to send the messages.

In my case, the applications send a "register" message to the server to let the server application know the token ids.